# Find hidden input value on same table row as checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a Table in which I have checkboxes that onclick on checkboxes I want to know 2 things

1. ID of the checkbox
2. ID of the hidden field on same table row

So I do have a hidden field in each row and I want to know what that value is

My checkbox I can see from my Fiddle is GridView1__ctl3_chkOut  but then I want jquery to find the value of the hidden field in same table row

I see that   GridView1__ctl2_hndTxtId   value is  3601   , but I will have many rows ...

Fiddle  -->  http://jsfiddle.net/bthorn/x9fc28nn/2/

**jquery**

```
$('.out').on('change', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.out').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    console.log(this.id);
    //what is the hidden field value in same row?
});
$('.yesno').on('change', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.yesno').not(this).prop('checked', false);
     //what is the hidden field value in same row?
});
```

console.log shows me the ID

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td style="width:5px;">
        <input type="hidden" name="GridView1:_ctl2:hndTxtId" id="GridView1__ctl2_hndTxtId" value="3601">
    </td>
    <td style="width:50px;">    <span id="GridView1__ctl2_lblVehicle0">413</span>

    </td>
    <td style="width:150px;"> <span id="GridView1__ctl2_lblName2">LONG</span>

    </td>
    <td style="width:100px;"> <span id="GridView1__ctl2_lblEquip2">BKT/TDR/M</span>

    </td>
    <td style="width:150px;">   <span id="GridView1__ctl2_lblScheduleb">0600-1430</span>

    </td>
    <td style="width:50px;"> <span id="GridView1__ctl2_lblScheduleOrig2">8</span>

    </td>
    <td style="width:150px;"> <span id="GridView1__ctl2_lblTimeOn"></span>

    </td>
    <td style="width:150px;"> <span id="GridView1__ctl2_lblTimeOff"></span>

    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="GridView1__ctl2_chkOut" type="checkbox" name="GridView1:_ctl2:chkOut" checked="checked" class="out">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="GridView1__ctl2_chkYes2" type="checkbox" name="GridView1:_ctl2:chkYes2" checked="checked" class="yesno">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="GridView1__ctl2_chkNo2" type="checkbox" name="GridView1:_ctl2:chkNo2" class="yesno">
    </td>
    <td style="width:5px;">
        <input type="submit" name="GridView1:_ctl2:AddButton0" value="On" onclick="setDateTimeOn(this); return false;" language="javascript" id="GridView1__ctl2_AddButton0" class="btn-blue">
    </td>
    <td style="width:150px;">
        <input name="GridView1:_ctl2:txtStormTimeOn" type="text" value="9-15-2015 12:00" id="GridView1__ctl2_txtStormTimeOn">
    </td>
    <td style="width:5px;">
        <input type="submit" name="GridView1:_ctl2:OffButton" value="Off" onclick="setDateTimeOn(this); return false;" language="javascript" id="GridView1__ctl2_OffButton" class="btn-blue">
    </td>
    <td style="width:150px;">
        <input name="GridView1:_ctl2:txtStormTimeOff" type="text" value="9-15-2015 12:28" id="GridView1__ctl2_txtStormTimeOff">
    </td>
    <td style="width:500px;"> <span id="GridView1__ctl2_lblComments"></span>

    </td>
    <td style="width:500px;">
        <input name="GridView1:_ctl2:txtStormComments" type="text" value="testfasdfsdfasdfsadfasdfsadf" maxlength="200" id="GridView1__ctl2_txtStormComments" style="width:200px;">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="width:5px;">
        <input type="hidden" name="GridView1:_ctl2:hndTxtId" id="GridView1__ctl2_hndTxtId" value="3601">
    </td>
    <td style="width:50px;">    <span id="GridView1__ctl3_lblVehicle0">215</span>

    </td>
    <td style="width:150px;"> <span id="GridView1__ctl3_lblName2">MORGAN</span>

    </td>
    <td style="width:100px;"> <span id="GridView1__ctl3_lblEquip2">BKT/TDR</span>

    </td>
    <td style="width:150px;">   <span id="GridView1__ctl3_lblScheduleb">0600-1430</span>

    </td>
    <td style="width:50px;"> <span id="GridView1__ctl3_lblScheduleOrig2">8</span>

    </td>
    <td style="width:150px;"> <span id="GridView1__ctl3_lblTimeOn"></span>

    </td>
    <td style="width:150px;"> <span id="GridView1__ctl3_lblTimeOff"></span>

    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="GridView1__ctl3_chkOut" type="checkbox" name="GridView1:_ctl3:chkOut" class="out">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="GridView1__ctl3_chkYes2" type="checkbox" name="GridView1:_ctl3:chkYes2" class="yesno">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="GridView1__ctl3_chkNo2" type="checkbox" name="GridView1:_ctl3:chkNo2" class="yesno">
    </td>
    <td style="width:5px;">
        <input type="submit" name="GridView1:_ctl3:AddButton0" value="On" onclick="setDateTimeOn(this); return false;" language="javascript" id="GridView1__ctl3_AddButton0" class="btn-blue">
    </td>
    <td style="width:150px;">
        <input name="GridView1:_ctl3:txtStormTimeOn" type="text" id="GridView1__ctl3_txtStormTimeOn">
    </td>
    <td style="width:5px;">
        <input type="submit" name="GridView1:_ctl3:OffButton" value="Off" onclick="setDateTimeOn(this); return false;" language="javascript" id="GridView1__ctl3_OffButton" class="btn-blue">
    </td>
    <td style="width:150px;">
        <input name="GridView1:_ctl3:txtStormTimeOff" type="text" id="GridView1__ctl3_txtStormTimeOff">
    </td>
    <td style="width:500px;"> <span id="GridView1__ctl3_lblComments"></span>

    </td>
    <td style="width:500px;">
        <input name="GridView1:_ctl3:txtStormComments" type="text" maxlength="200" id="GridView1__ctl3_txtStormComments" style="width:200px;">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the downvote,  trolling must be fun hobby cause I'm sure you have no questions and you know all the perfect questions to ask.   :/   meh

Comment: Thank you to everyone else that gives freely from their knowledge to help me and others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already got the ID of the `checkbox`. To get the value of the `hidden input field` of the row use the following code:

```
$('.yesno').on('change', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="hidden"]').val()
});
```

See this **[JSfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x9fc28nn/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can find information about the selectors at : https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Taking a part of your fiddle, it looks about:

```
$tr = $(this).closest('tr');
hidden = $tr.find('input[type="hidden"]');
console.log(hidden);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the find method as you are already using but with `'input[type=hidden]'`:

```
$('.out').on('change', function () {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    $tr.find('.out').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    console.log(this.id);
    //what is the hidden field value in same row?
    var hiddenVal = $tr.find('input[type=hidden]').val();
    console.log(hiddenVal);
});
$('.yesno').on('change', function () {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    $tr.find('.yesno').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    //what is the hidden field value in same row?
    var hiddenVal = $tr.find('input[type=hidden]').val();
    console.log(hiddenVal);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x9fc28nn/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You already have the id of the checkbox. You can get the id of the hidden input element using:

```
var hiddenID = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=hidden]').prop('id');
```

And you can get the value of the same field like so:

```
var hiddenVal = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=hidden]').val();
```